# Apache port forwarding

Tags: apache-2.2

Some muppet in my company has bunged up the config of an apache server. Basically what I need to do to fix this mess is to capture all traffic on port 8082 (Apache is configured to listen to this port) - then to redirect this traffic to /bugzilla. Is this possible, and if so how?

The box is only visible to internal users so quick dirty hack is just fine in this case.

Comment: Bunged up in what way, what does it do right now?

Comment: Could you define muppet for those that don't understand the term please :)

Answer (score 3):

*Quick and dirty*... Install a TCP proxy to redirect the packages from 8082 to another port and maybe another machine. [rinetd](http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/) is really easy and has worked good for me before.

Comment: this solution worked perfectly - thank you very much victor!