# Change port and host using .htaccess

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, port-forwarding

I am trying to use `mod_rewrite` to basically port forward a port on a subdomain to another port on another IP.

Like this:

```
sub.website.com:2000 --> 123.45.67.891:3000
```

How could this be accomplished using a `.htaccess` file with  `mod_rewrite`?

I have tried the following but to no avail:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.website.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^2000$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://123.45.67.891:3000/$1 [L,R=302]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this in your `.htaccess`.

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.website.com:2000 [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) https://123.45.67.891:3000/$1 [R=301,L]
```

You can also look the accepted answer here (http://www.webmasterworld.com/apache/3264071.htm). R=301 is used for permanent redirection. If you wish to use temporary redirection, use R=302 instead.

If it doesn't help, you can try enabling proxy in your apache: (edit your /etc/apache2/httpd.conf)

```
LoadModule proxy_module modules/mod_proxy.so
LoadModule proxy_http_module modules/mod_proxy_http.so

ProxyRequests Off

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<VirtualHost sub.website.com:2000>
    ServerName  redirecting
    ServerAdmin admin@website.com

    ProxyRequests off
    ProxyPass / http://123.45.67.891:3000
</VirtualHost>
```

(look the solution posted here [Apache port forwarding](https://serverfault.com/questions/41930/apache-port-forwarding)).

Comment: Thanks but I've had no luck with that, i'm trying it [here](http://zk.squaredtiki.com:2000) with port 2000 but Safari just tells me that the server where the page is located is not responding.

Comment: Did you try to restart apache?

Comment: Still no joy unfortunately

Comment: My `.htaacess` file: http://pastebin.com/RB8K1Dhi

Comment: Is your server actually listening to port 2000? If safari times out this usually means that your server isn't responding at all.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to do this with RewriteRules in .htaccess files. 
You problem is that .htaccess files are only read after the server has gone through the URL-to-filename translation phase. Only after a server has come to the (preliminary) conclusion that the resource it needs to serve exists on it's filesystem will it start reading the relevant .htaccess files. 
So it might be that your .htaccess file isn't ever read for these requests. Enable rewritelog to find this out.

You should do this in the main server config.